# Yawning or mouth open/close image dataset

Tags: data-request, images, faces

I'm new to machine learning and having a hard time collecting dataset. I'm promise this is for study purpose only, no bussiness included.

Comment: I'd personally take snaps of a bunch of your friends with their mouths open or closed, or request they take one and send it to you. That would give you a start at least? I suspect you are after 1000s of images, which are time consuming to collect. Alternatively you could try a google image search.